# (Javascript) Can a global function contain locally declared variables?

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm currently working on a codewars kata (Convert RGB number (0-255) to hexadecimal) and came across something interesting when trying to improve the readability of my code. I want to construct a global function to work with local variables, but when I try to run the code it throws an undefined error on the "j" variable (and also presumably the "i" variable). Code below:

```
function rgb(r, g, b){
  let x
  let y
  let z
  function conversion(){
    switch(j) {
            case 10:
              j = 'A'
              break
            case 11:
              j = 'B'
              break
            case 12:
              j = 'C'
              break
            case 13:
              j = 'D'
              break
            case 14:
              j = 'E'
              break
            case 15:
              j = 'F'
          }
          switch(i) {
            case 10:
              i = 'A'
              break
            case 11:
              i = 'B'
              break
            case 12:
              i = 'C'
              break
            case 13:
              i = 'D'
              break
            case 14:
              i = 'E'
              break
            case 15:
              i = 'F'
          }
  }
  if (r <= 0) {
    x = '00'
  } else if (r >= 255) {
      x = 'FF'
    } else {
        let i = Math.floor(r / 16)
        let j = Math.floor(r - i * 16)
        conversion()
        x = i.toString() + j.toString()
      }
  if (g <= 0) {
    y = '00'
  } else if (g >= 255) {
      y = 'FF'
    } else {
        let i = Math.floor(g / 16)
        let j = Math.floor(g - i * 16)
        conversion()
        y = i.toString() + j.toString()
      }
  if (b <= 0) {
    z = '00'
  } else if (b >= 255) {
      z = 'FF'
    } else {
        let i = Math.floor(b / 16)
        let j = Math.floor(b - i * 16)
        conversion()
        z = i.toString() + j.toString()
      }
  return x + y + z
}
```

So as you can see, it would be nicer to use the "conversion" function rather than copy paste all that code three times. Any ideas on this topic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass `i` and `j` as parameters.

Comment: you should take i and j as parameters of the conversion function:function conversion(i,j){...}, and call it with conversion(i,j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared with `let` and `const` are block-scoped. Your current setup doesn't work because `i` and `j` aren't declared within any of `conversion`'s surrounding blocks.

While you could (begin to) fix it by declaring `i` and `j` in the outer function body:

```
function rgb(r, g, b){
  let x
  let y
  let z
  let j;
  let i;
  function conversion(){
```

It would be better to have `conversion` simply `return` the converted value, and assign the converted value to `i` or `j`. You can also make the rest of the code significantly less repetitive by making another function for converting the `r`, `g`, and `b` parameters, and then call that function 3 times, instead of copy-pasting the same sort of thing 3 times.

Also note that, to figure out the one's place, you can use *just* the modulo operator `%` on the number instead of having to subtract from the floored `i`.

```js
function rgb(r, g, b) {
  // parameter should be 0-15
  function convertToSingleHexDigit(num) {
    return num <= 9
      ? String(num)
      : String.fromCharCode(55 + num); // 65 corresponds to A, 66 corresponds to B, etc
  }
  // parameter should be 0-255
  function convertNum(num) {
    const i = convertToSingleHexDigit(Math.floor(num / 16));
    const j = convertToSingleHexDigit(Math.floor(num % 16));
    return i + j;
  }
  return convertNum(r) + convertNum(g) + convertNum(b);
}
console.log(rgb(255, 255, 255));
console.log(rgb(100, 200, 100));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared `i` and `j` with `let`, their scope is just the `else` blocks where you declared them. Since `conversion()` is not defined inside those blocks, it can't access the variables.

You could declare the variables at the top of the function, and then assign them in the `else` blocks. Then they would be in the scope anything within the function, including the nested `conversion()` function.

But it would be better to just make them function parameters and return values.

```
function rgb(r, g, b){
  let x
  let y
  let z
  function conversion(){
    switch(j) {
            case 10:
              j = 'A'
              break
            case 11:
              j = 'B'
              break
            case 12:
              j = 'C'
              break
            case 13:
              j = 'D'
              break
            case 14:
              j = 'E'
              break
            case 15:
              j = 'F'
          }
          switch(i) {
            case 10:
              i = 'A'
              break
            case 11:
              i = 'B'
              break
            case 12:
              i = 'C'
              break
            case 13:
              i = 'D'
              break
            case 14:
              i = 'E'
              break
            case 15:
              i = 'F'
          }
    return [i, j]
  }
  if (r <= 0) {
    x = '00'
  } else if (r >= 255) {
      x = 'FF'
    } else {
        let i = Math.floor(r / 16)
        let j = Math.floor(r - i * 16)
        [i, j] = conversion(i, j)
        x = i.toString() + j.toString()
      }
  if (g <= 0) {
    y = '00'
  } else if (g >= 255) {
      y = 'FF'
    } else {
        let i = Math.floor(g / 16)
        let j = Math.floor(g - i * 16)
        [i, j] = conversion(i, j)
        y = i.toString() + j.toString()
      }
  if (b <= 0) {
    z = '00'
  } else if (b >= 255) {
      z = 'FF'
    } else {
        let i = Math.floor(b / 16)
        let j = Math.floor(b - i * 16)
        [i, j] = conversion(i, j)
        z = i.toString() + j.toString()
      }
  return x + y + z
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code that you have not declared j and i. Declare it either in outer function or inner function to make it work.

```js
function rgb(r, g, b){
  let x
  let y
  let z
  // in outer function 
  let i;
  let j; 


  function conversion(){
    // in lkocal function here 
    // let j ;
    // let i; 

    switch(j) {
            case 10:
              j = 'A'
              break
            case 11:
              j = 'B'
              break
            case 12:
              j = 'C'
              break
            case 13:
              j = 'D'
              break
            case 14:
              j = 'E'
              break
            case 15:
              j = 'F'
          }
          switch(i) {
            case 10:
              i = 'A'
              break
            case 11:
              i = 'B'
              break
            case 12:
              i = 'C'
              break
            case 13:
              i = 'D'
              break
            case 14:
              i = 'E'
              break
            case 15:
              i = 'F'
          }
  }
  if (r <= 0) {
    x = '00'
  } else if (r >= 255) {
      x = 'FF'
    } else {
        let i = Math.floor(r / 16)
        let j = Math.floor(r - i * 16)
        conversion()
        x = i.toString() + j.toString()
      }
  if (g <= 0) {
    y = '00'
  } else if (g >= 255) {
      y = 'FF'
    } else {
        let i = Math.floor(g / 16)
        let j = Math.floor(g - i * 16)
        conversion()
        y = i.toString() + j.toString()
      }
  if (b <= 0) {
    z = '00'
  } else if (b >= 255) {
      z = 'FF'
    } else {
        let i = Math.floor(b / 16)
        let j = Math.floor(b - i * 16)
        conversion()
        z = i.toString() + j.toString()
      }
  return x + y + z
}


var r = rgb(56,67,90);

console.log(r);
```